# How can I conditionally send templates and javascript files to the client in meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

This is related to a previous question I asked about [conditionally sending document data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074434/how-do-you-conditionally-send-data-to-the-client-in-meteor) to the client in [meteor](http://meteor.com).

Lets say I have a [parse-like data editor/browser](http://blog.parse.com/2012/12/20/the-new-data-browser-2/) available for user accounts marked as system admin, as well as some pages that show logging information about the app. I'm using [meteor-router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) and a filter to accomplish this.

99% of users won't need to to see those interfaces, but the (massive amounts of) javascript for them is still sent to the client. The admin specific javascript and templates are separated into their own files, **how can I make sure they are not sent to the client unnecessarily (when the logged in user is not an admin)?**

Is the best option really to **split the admin interface into a separate app and point it at the original's mongo**?

Comment: seems like I asked same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586986/how-to-determine-which-css-file-will-be-sent-to-clients/18591051?noredirect=1#18591051

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want Meteor to load your client-side scripts automatically, you could place them in the /public directory and load them yourself when you need them.

However, in the case of an admin environment, it may actually be better from a software development perspective to separate all of that into its own app, pointing to the same database like you said.

Comment: What about not loading certain template files except on demand?

Comment: No idea. I don't think that's possible or something you want, since Meteor has to parse all the template files and generate the accompanying template javascript to be able to track them, etc.

Comment: I found a package (2 in fact) that does exactly what you are suggesting:
https://atmospherejs.com/numtel/publicsources and 
https://atmospherejs.com/numtel/privatesources

It uses an iron-router plug-in to load your specific files from /public or /private folder.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment (June 2015), [incremental template loading is still on the Meteor Roadmap](https://trello.com/c/24s6vyxo/55-incremental-loading).

The best solution might actually be to split away the admin app, also [for security reasons](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/55381/is-it-reasonable-to-keep-control-panel-in-separate-subdomain-or-domain/55443#55443).

If you do want to keep everything in one app, the leading community package for lazy loading is [numtel:lazy-bundles](https://forums.meteor.com/t/lazy-load-source-bundles-with-new-numtel-lazy-bundles-package/5098).