# how to determine which css file will be sent to clients

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, url-routing

I started a simple project with [Meteor](http://www.meteor.com/). But now it is getting complicated. I am trying add a management panel for project. I want to separate site and its panel. But every css and js files are both sent to site and management.

Environment: I am hosting project at meteor.com. My development machine is Windows 7. I cant use meteorite. If you are going to suggest me to use mrt add router, you are welcome. but currently i cant do it.

Current directory structure:

- client (client.js, index.html, css files, other js files like jquery plugins)
- server (server.js)
- public (image files for UI)

### Update

I have 1 index file which is:

```
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>

<body>
    {{> root}}
</body>
```

root template is using some other templates inside. I may use 2 different index files. 1 for site and 1 for management panel.

root template:

```
<template name="root">
    {{#if adminURL}}
        {{> adminLogin}}
    {{else}}
        {{> site}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

adminLogin template:

```
<template name="adminLogin">
    {{#if currentUser}}
        {{> management}}
    {{else}}
        admin login page.
            <div style="float: right">
              {{loginButtons align="right"}}
            </div>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

management template:

```
<template name="management">
    <div id="header" class="navbar">
       ....
    </div>
    <div id="container" class="row-fluid">
       ....
    </div>
</template>
```

site template:

```
<template name="management">
     <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</template>
```

Answer (score 3):

TLDR; If you put your files over in the `/public` folder, they wont automatically be sent to the client, they just need to be referenced manually.

To reference your files manually, just add them into your HTML just before where your `</body>` is. So for a file at `/public/js/myFile1.js` :

```
    <script type="text/javascript"  src="/js/myFile1.js"></script>
</body>
```

All of the following are sent to the client, all js,css,font & html files in the top level (root directory that & subdirectories that aren't:

- server
- public
- assets
- packages
- public
- folders that begin with a '.'
- or tests (not sure)

are all concatenated into a single  file and sent to the client.

So in the public folder meteor pretty much ignores them. You can manually reference them to include them if you wish.

Another option might be to make a private package so you can explicitly decide on which files you want to include, this makes it easy to also use your same design on different related meteor apps.

Comment: Will you please clearify your answer? How is it possible to reference files manually? I am editing my question according to your answer.

Comment: I have edited the answer to reflect how to reference files too

Comment: I tried you suggestion. Inside root template, with a helper, I am selecting which template to be shown. If an admin template will be shown, I added necessary css and js files at the bottom of the template. With this way, I am passing css files for only admin panel. But this is not a very efficient way to do this. css files must locate inside head tags.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work in templates as such, it works for all templates if you want to reference them with just behind `</body>`. With CSS files you need to have one css file and then split your classes up for each template. Meteor apps are technically on a single page so you can't split up each template to have its own CSS files as they would be loaded anyway. You can use inline styles if you want, but its still better to use a single stylesheet and split the classes up for each template.

Comment: it is not a convenient way that use singe html and css file for both cms and site itself. they should be separate from eachother. one possible option to create 2 different applications for each of them. meteor is so new for such complexity it seems. I will investigate this further.